# where is .so in flutter

Tags: flutter, decompiler

I didn't find the 'lib' folder and '.so' files in my Flutter application. What could be the issue?

I decompiled some Flutter apps and didn't find any .so files.

In theory, Flutter-developed apps should have 'libflutter.so' representing the Flutter engine and 'libapp.so' representing Dart code. But why are they missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.